# Are the join types defined as constants somewhere accessible in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I haven't found them after having a cursory glance at the Spark codebase. In most documentation and tutorial examples, people seem to be using 'naked' string literals to specify join types. Does Spark provide an object or class defining "leftouter", "inner", "cartesian" etc. as public **val**s, or is relying on string literals simply the convention?

That is to say, is there an alternative to:

```
dataframe.join(
  right = anotherDataFrame,
  joinExprs = expr("1 = 1"),
  joinType = "leftouter"
)
```

that would look something like:

```
dataframe.join(
  right = anotherDataFrame, 
  joinExprs = expr("1 = 1"),
  joinType = SparkJoins.LeftOuter
)
```

?

Comment: There seem to be no such constants, at least not in version 2.2.1, see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/joinTypes.scala#L25-L45...

Comment: @TzachZohar, that's the same conclusion I've arrived at too. I find it a curious; it seems like a very common pattern to provide case classes for the a set of known values, to make pattern matching (for instance) easier - to the point where I wonder if this was a deliberate omission, and what the arguments for leaving it out was.

Comment: Agreed; The only "reasoning" I can think of is SparkSQL's attempt to be as language-agnostic and as close to SQL as possible: so having plain text such as `"leftjoin"` in code examples and docs would be more usable regardless of the language you're using; Generally speaking Spark SQL (DataFrame API) favors compatibility over compile-time type safety (almost everything is checked only in runtime) so maybe this is just another example of this approach. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the the objects included in the package, for instance, using the following objects for each literal:

- for "INNER" => `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.Inner.sql`
- for "LEFT OUTER" => `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.LeftOuter.sql`
- etc.

source: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/joinTypes.scala

Comment: This does not work for `LEFT OUTER` - it would not be matched to `left` or `leftouter` as the space is not transformed. You would have to replace the blank with an underscore yourself.